# Running pyramid and django side by side

Tags: python, django, pyramid

We have a pyramid application that provides API endpoint. Now we want to implement frontend as well but to our surprise, i10n/l10n tooling in pyramid is not as good as in django. So I have been thinking what if we implement the frontend with django instead? So I manage to get the PoC running with this code:-

```
# in pyramid main() entry point
def main(global_config: t.Dict[str, str], **settings: str) -> Router:
    """Return a Pyramid WSGI application."""

    # Expand environment variables in .ini files
    settings = expandvars_dict(settings)
    settings["ini_path"] = global_config["__file__"]

    # Configure Pyramid
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    configure(config)

    # Up, Up and Away!
    from myapp.wsgi import application as django_app
    pyramid_app = config.make_wsgi_app()

    def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
        request_url = environ["PATH_INFO"]
        if request_url.startswith("/api"):
            return pyramid_app(environ, start_response)

        return django_app(environ, start_response)

    return wsgi_app
```

Basically the idea is that, for any request path that starts with `/api`, we pass it to pyramid, while everything else will be handled by django. This seems to be working well for a simple pages I'm testing, with all the i10n/l10n stuff also working. I'm wondering if there's any gotchas that I should be aware of, if I'm going this route.

Comment: And how is it deployed? If you have nginx, for example, then routing on server level would be faster then `startswith` on python level (location `/api` mapped to pyramid wsgi app, location `/` to django wsgi app). It also allows for better containerization, having nginx, pyramid and django in three separate containers without interference. I don't see anything wrong with this approach either, it *may* affect performance, but I cannot estimate the percentage - just try and see if you get slower.

Comment: It's on heroku so I can't use nginx to do the routing, at least not without more elaborate setup that I'm not willing to spend time yet for now. I'm not worry much about performance (yet), but more on things like django messing up with some global stuff etc.

Comment: If you encounter unexpected behavior and think it can be related to django initialization, move `from myapp.wsgi` import to function body, so that it happens only when requested endpoint is not `/api`. However, IMO it shouldn't interfere, in general this looks like an interesting pattern I never thought of.